# Retrive exit URL query in WordPress

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm trying to pass some data from a page in Wordpress to another. The information is being appended in the URL this way:

```
www.url.com/example/?wpt_result_title[0]=some+name
```

So I'm using a php to do it, in my function.php code I have added this:

```
function add_query_vars_filter( $vars ) {
  $vars[] = "wpt_result_title";
  return $vars;
}
add_filter( 'query_vars', 'add_query_vars_filter' );
```

And in code in the page is this one:

```
<? php
echo "hello ";

    $vars = (get_query_var('wpt_result_title[0]')) get_query_var('wpt_result_title[0]') : false;

if($vars){
     echo 'It works and Gives result= ' . $vars;
}


echo "World ";

  ?>
```

But I'm only getting the "hello World" text. 
What am I missing?

Thanks

Comment: Can you run `var_dump(get_query_var('wpt_result_title'))` and let me know the output? Do you have control over the URL that's being built?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If that is truly the code you are using, then there are a few mistakes.  Since you are getting "Hello World", I assume you have a typo here only, and not in your code.  Regardless... your line:

`$vars = (get_query_var('wpt_result_title[0]')) get_query_var('wpt_result_title[0]') : false;`

Should become:

`$vars = get_query_var('wpt_result_title') ? get_query_var('wpt_result_title') : false;`

Or better yet, just leave it as `$vars = get_query_var('wpt_result_title')` as it will return an empty string if it doesn't exist, and you can then check `if( ! empty( $vars ) )`.

Then, considering you are passing an array in the query string, $vars "should" be an array... so:

`echo 'It works and Gives result= ' . $vars;`

Theoretically would output 'It works and Gives result= Array'.  So you'd need to either loop through the values of `$vars`, or use `$vars[0]`.